# Wait exact a second in wait method tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a countdown program in python using `tkinter`. Everything works perfect whereas `root.after(1000, Counter)`, where `Counter` is function which updates seconds, takes more than `1` second to update another seconds. With lots of searching, I got this [Where time is being lost after and before calling after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874825/have-after-method-run-on-time-tkinter) by `Bryan Oakley`.

How can I wait for exact 1 second?

Comment: I strongly suspect that following @Bryan Oakley's advice on this subject is the closest you're going to be able to get using `tkinter`.

Comment: As per your advice, I can conclude that waiting exact a second in tkinter is not really possible, is it ?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the case.

Comment: Thank you very much @martineau for the adivce

Comment: If some milliseconds is lost while  updating other widget in **tkinter** then how Microsoft, Apple, Android, etc maintain exact time?

Comment: Most modern computers have a hardware clock.

Comment: Huge thanks again for the information.